# stderr - error when trying to deploy expo react native app build

Tags: react-native, npm

I have a react native project I am currently building with expo in order to deploy to the apple app store. When the react native start to build after I run `eas build --platform ios` it starts going through the build process. when it gets to the `installing dependencies` portion, I keep getting a bunch of `WARN` errors and I want to fix them but not sure how to exactly.

full set of errors:

```
Running "npm install" in directory 'Reipp' 
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[stderr] npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
added 1326 packages in 21s
61 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings are perfectly normal in any project using Javascript basically. Most of them are outside of your control, especially as you are using Expo in your project.

If you want to fix those that are under your control, I recommend you to run `expo doctor` from your terminal, this will show you if there are any inconsistencies that you actually can (and should) fix.